# Remove MouseOver state on control in Windows 8

Tags: wpf, xaml, mouseover, itemtemplate, visualstatemanager

I simplified my problem with a sample application. So I have a list with some objects represented by a rectangle.

But I have a problem if my application turn on Windows 8. A blue rectangle appears around my rectangles when I place my mouse over the element. I tried some solutions found on the internet, but none of them work.

My code :

```
<Window x:Class="Test_application.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test_application"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid Background="DarkGray">
    <ListBox Margin="10" x:Name="lbTest">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Segment}">
                <Rectangle Width="150" Height="10" Stroke="Gray" StrokeThickness="1.354" Margin="10"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.Resources>
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

[image: Application]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The selection and mouseover colors are defined in `Triggers` in the `ControlTemplate` for ListBoxItem so you'll need to customize that if you want to use different (or no) color for them. Depending on how much of the original trigger functionality you want you can make a copy of the original one (Blend will do this for you) and modify it or just use something simple like this:

```
        <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding X}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Y}"/>
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{x:Null}" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                            <Border x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                                  VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            </Border>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Alternatively, you should consider whether you actually need a `ListBox` or could just use a base `ItemsControl`, which has none of the mouseover behavior you're trying to get rid of. The decision should be based on whether or not you need item selection, as this is the primary thing that `ListBox` adds.

Comment: Oh my god! It's work!! :)
I've searched every time of today and you find the solution.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Default highlight can be overriden.

```
<ListView.Resources>
    ...
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Orange" />
    ...
</ListView.Resources>
```

Instead `Orange` color set `Transparent` or `#00FFFFFF`.

**EDIT:**

Or add trigger to ItemContainerStyle

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    ...
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>       
    ...
</Style>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I've already try it, but it doesn't work. :-s